# Cycles SSS surface colour

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I am looking at improving a characters Skin material node setup.

Most of the Node setups I have seen for cycles, including the Arnold Skin port basically involve (not including gloss, bump etc) several SSS shaders mixed together to provide Epidermal, Sub dermal and deep scattering. With the surface colour input on the SSS shader used to provide the various scatter colours.

I do not think this is physically correct. Surely the surface colour for these SSS shaders should be the Diffuse colour not the scatter colour?

Most of the other Non-blender skin shaders I have seen seem to separate surface colour and Scatter colour.

If I plug for instance, a sub dermal colour map into the radius input will this effect the scatter colour of the shader? Or is this input only for vector information?

Or do I need to set the colour input to the diffuse colour - radius and scale to an appropriate value and then use a texture map to mix this SSS shader with other SSS shaders?

Comment: Physically correct means that the materials interact with light like they would in the real world. If the shader actually looks like skin is another thing. The skin shader tries to mimic the real world skin. You can't really cut up your skin into layered of shaders, it is a hard thing to do. THe Arnold Skin shader is very good and the port is an accurate representation of it. I would just use the Arnold Port

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You've got several questions, but none of them are very clear.